# ¿Cómo colocar un botón a la derecha en un formulario?

Tags: html, css

Tengo este formulario, pero siento que el lado izquierdo esta muy sobrecargado, por lo que quiero que el botón de "enviar" este en la derecha, y no en la izquierda.

```css
.campo {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.campo__label {
    flex: 0 0 9rem;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.campo__field {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid var(--gris);
    border-radius: .5rem;
}

.campo__field--textarea {
    height: 20rem;

}
```

```html
<form class="formulario">
    <div class="campo">
        <label class="campo__label" for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input class="campo__field" type="text" placeholder="Tu Nombre" id="nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
        <label class="campo__label" for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input class="campo__field"  type="email" placeholder="Tu E-mail" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
        <label class="campo__label" for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
        <textarea class="campo__field campo__field--textarea" id="mensaje"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
        <div class="campo__boton">
            <input type="submit" value="enviar" class="boton boton--primario">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ya intente con `justify-content: right;`, con `margin-rigth: 0;`, con `float: right;`, y ya ni me acuerdo con que mas.
Debe ser algo simple pero simplemente no encuentro la solución.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo solucionas de esta forma:

```
.campo:last-child {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

- Seleccionamos [el último elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) de aquellos que tienen la clase `campo`
- Desplazamos al botón de este último elemento a la derecha aprovechando las funcionalidades de [flexbox, en este caso `justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#sintaxis)

Comment: Pero que... Eso fue lo primero que intenté y no me funcionó. Le había agregado una tercera clase al botón y le había dado justify-content: flex-end; y no me había funcionado. ¿Que hice mal? Hice lo mismo solo que seleccionado el botón de otra forma.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar ponerle un margin-left de 28em por ejemplo al 'boton' respecto a su div para moverlo a la derecha con CSS... o un padding-left al div campo_boton.